# how to disable the fragment from navigation drawer android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-navigation

I am developing my first android application. please any one help me from my issue. In my application i am using navigation drawer, i added fragments in navigation drawer. Based on condition i need disable one fragment from drawer.
cased on mainvendorid i need to add the fragment to navigation drawer. If mainvendorid one i need to add.
my code:

Main_Activity:

```
class MySimpleRightArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;
        public Integer[] sideimages = { R.drawable.orders, R.drawable.cash,
                R.drawable.contact, R.drawable.profilee, R.drawable.changepassword,R.drawable.profilee };

        public MySimpleRightArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item_two, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_two,
                    parent, false);

            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tx_n_text);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_side);
            textView.setTypeface(custom_bold);

            textView.setText(mNavagarighttitles[position]);
            imageview.setImageResource(sideimages[position]);
            // change the icon for Windows and iPhone

            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

frag:

```
private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        String mainvendorid=m_sharedPreference.getString("VendorID", "");
        Log.v("TAG_MAINNNNNN", "" + mainvendorid);

            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Previousorders_Fragment.class.getName()));



        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Retailer_Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Wallet_Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Commissions_fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ChangePassword_Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Message_fragment.class.getName()));

        this.mPagerAdapter = new Menu_adapter(super.getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);

        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

string.xml:

```
<string-array name="navagation_bar_right">/

    <item> Transactions </item>
    <item> Retailers </item>
    <item> Wallet</item>
    <item> Commissions</item>
    <item> Profile</item>
    <item> Messages</item>

</string-array>
```

Comment: What exactly you want? Disable means not clickable or dont allow to open it? you have also mentioned pager in code, Is that related with drawer?

Comment: @Harry disable maeans,,,not able to see in navigation drawer. yes,i mentioned this navagation drawer items to view pager. how i disable fragment (from navigation drawer and view pager) when mainendor=0

Comment: Disable swipe and also should not open from left-top icon. Right?

Comment: that fragment at navagation drawer first position and first position of view pager too

Comment: Ok, so particular fragment should be invisible in drawer as well as from pager!

Comment: ya @harry...particular fragment from drawer and pager too

Comment: you have to remove particular item from 'values' and from 'fragments' and have to call notifyDataSetChanged() on both adapter.

Comment: how to remove particular item for values for paricular condition?

Comment: I mentioned in my comment the arraylist variable names, remove item by position whatever you want!

Comment: what about view pager?

Comment: Why are not you reading comment properly? what is 'fragments'? Isn't arraylist for viewpatger adapter!!

Comment: fragment is not removing fromnavagation drawer

Comment: any one help me from my issue

Comment: @harry, could you please tell me how to remove those particulat items. i trired but i failed. help me

Comment: pass arraylist of string values in 'MySimpleRightArrayAdapter' and from activity remove item from arraylist and call (MySimpleRightArrayAdapter obj).notifyDataSetChanged();